# Is there a way to access wifi in Zurich airport without a phone service?

Tags: wifi, zrh

I am traveling through Zurich and have a phone without any roaming there; I'm planning on picking up a SIM once I get to my final destination. Last time I was there, I couldn't access the airport wifi because it required a code sent via SMS.

In the event I need to contact someone or coordinate about flight delays, is there some alternate way to get wifi access?

Comment: Is your current SIM or your final destination SIM compatible with the network in Zurich? What would the cost be to receive a single SMS on international roaming?

Comment: Current SIM is an MVNO and it's my understanding that texts simply do not work internationally — there's not even an option to pay piecemeal. Presumably, I could have ordered the destination SIM in advance and had it shipped to me... but let's assume I didn't.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[This link to Zürich Airport](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/internet-and-app) handles your problem.

> #### How to log on
>
> - Select the ZurichAirport WLAN network
> - Launch the browser (e.g.: Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, …) on the device
> - A connection to the login page is created automatically
> - Select „Register“
> - After registering, a code will be sent via text message
> - Enter the code in the registration interface and click „Login“ (the code will be saved for twelve months)
>
> #### No mobile phone or problems with text message reception?
>
> For an access code you can use boarding pass scanners at the following locations:
>
> - Service Center (Airport Center, Level 1)
> - Information (Airside Center, Level 1)
> - Airside Center, Level 1 beim Transit Hotel
> - Switzerlandinfo, Arrival 2
> - Gates E, Level 2 next to Starbucks
> - Gates E, Level 2 next to Alpenblick Bar
> - Gates A, opposite to Starbucks (A63)

Comment: And you can probably get away with using a fake boarding pass, to avoid revealing your identity: https://shooshx.github.io/BoardingBarcode/

Answer (score 3):

Zurich airport offers also mobile wifi hotspots with unlimited high speed data.
I think they just started with that rental service. It's not a free service though. But sounds quite convenient.
https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/information-desks

Answer (score 2):

I'm sitting in Zurich now.  They have a keosk you can scan your ticket and it will print a code.  Good for 2 hours free.  I've been down loading Netflix for the flight.  Very fast.